# How can I update table1 after update on table2?

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `gym`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `goods_input_total_amount-updateon-goods_input_price`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `goods_input_total_amount-updateon-goods_input_price`
    AFTER UPDATE ON `goods_input_price` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        DECLARE input_price INTEGER;
        SELECT price_goods_input_price INTO input_price FROM goods_input_price
        WHERE id_goods_input_price=NEW.id_goods_input_price LIMIT 1;
        SET new.goods_input_total_amount=goods_input_quantity*input_price;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I have this error message:

> Error Code: 1362 Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

Comment: Edit your question

Answer (score 2):

The message is pretty clear.  If you want to update the row, you need a *before* update trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE gym$$

DROP TRIGGER `goods_input_total_amount_updateon_goods_input_price`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `goods_input_total_amount_updateon_goods_input_price` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON goods_input_price
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE input_price INTEGER;
     SELECT price_goods_input_price INTO input_price
     FROM goods_input_price
     WHERE id_goods_input_price = NEW.id_goods_input_price
     LIMIT 1;

     SET new.goods_input_total_amount = goods_input_quantityinput_price;
 END; $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I would be inclined to write this as:

```
BEGIN
     SELECT price_goods_input_price 
     INTO new.goods_input_total_amount
     FROM goods_input_price
     WHERE id_goods_input_price = NEW.id_goods_input_price
     LIMIT 1;
END; $$
```

Comment: Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'goods_input_total_amount' in 'NEW'

this is in "before" case

Comment: and the last row is as follows

SET new.goods_input_total_amount = goods_input_quantity*input_price;

Comment: @Karen . . . The name of the trigger should not have hyphens.

Comment: @Karen . . . Let me rephrase that.  You should use identifiers that don't need to be escaped.  You are escaping your identifiers and I guess I removed the escape characters.  Of course, you can use hyphens with the back ticks, but it is better to not need them at all.

Comment: Gordon, can you review your second answer considering, that my last row is such as: SET new.goods_input_total_amount = goods_input_quantity*input_price; ? total amount and quantity are from another table. Thank you.

Comment: @Karen . . . According to your code, they are from the same table, `goods_input_price`.